# Why path generated by d3 js didn't display?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to create a map from json file in d3.js. The source code of my project is accessible from link of:[source code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dazzling-field-nyvrfd).
I have problem in making large the map. It's small and its size is not changable.
How can make it large and fit to its parent?